# How to solve numeric or value error?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

In the below program,  procedure('newprocedure') got succesfully created coz oresult return Success but this line >>>>
oresult oot = odb.ExecuteSQL("Begin newprocedur(:ENAME,:ROLLNO); End;"); its getting failed and getting this error>>>> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error" .Please help me with solutions.

And my table looks like this

Egtable

Roll Name 
1 kate 
3 Zac

```
`int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {
   OStartup();
   ODatabase odb;
   oresult res = odb.Open("MICROSOFT", "OMNIPOS", "OMNIPOS");
   char pSqlStmt[500];
   memset(pSqlStmt,0,sizeof(pSqlStmt));
   OSqlStmt osql;
   ///////////////////////////////procedure Creation/////////////////
   strcpy(pSqlStmt,"create or replace PROCEDURE newprocedure(inEmpName IN VARCHAR2 ,outEmpno   OUT NUMBER)\n AS \n"); 
  strcat(pSqlStmt,"BEGIN\n"); 
  strcat(pSqlStmt,"select ROLL into outEmpno from Egtable WHERE NAME = inEmpName;\n"); 
 // strcat(pSqlStmt,"dbms_output.put_line('Roll'+outEmpno);\n");
  strcat(pSqlStmt,"outEmpno:=outEmpno+1;\n");
  strcat(pSqlStmt,"update Egtable set ROLL = outEmpno WHERE NAME = inEmpName;\n");
  strcat(pSqlStmt,"END;\n");
  oresult ot = odb.ExecuteSQL(pSqlStmt);

  if (ot == OSUCCESS) 
  {  
   OValue val;
   odb.GetParameters().Add("ENAME","Zac", OPARAMETER_INVAR, OTYPE_VARCHAR2);
   odb.GetParameters().Add("ROLLNO",0, OPARAMETER_OUTVAR, OTYPE_NUMBER); 
   oresult oot = odb.ExecuteSQL("Begin newprocedure(:ENAME,:ROLLNO); End;");
   oresult i = odb.GetParameters().GetParameter("ROLLNO").GetValue(&val);
   cout<< "value is " << (const char*) val<<endl;
  }
  else
  { 
   cout<<"ERR:"<<odb.GetServerErrorText(); 
  } 
  odb.Close();
  OShutdown();
  }
```

`

Thanks in advance

Comment: if possible, please show your code.

Comment: Some value is too large for a variable: check for too short varchars to store the strings you're passing or constructing or numbers with not enough precision to store the values you're calculating. Analyze your code and data: where is the problem most likely to be?

Comment: Hi all i posted my code above, could you all please tell where i made mistake. Thanks

Comment: You do realise this ia a peculiar way of doing things?  Why not just create the procedure *once* and then just call it?

Comment: Thank you all, i got successfull result for above code, the problem is one more procedure i created is accessing the same table.So the executesql got failed everytime.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple syntax error.  Oracle only uses '+' for arithmetic.  So in this line of code ...

```
dbms_output.put_line('Roll'+outEmpno)
```

... it attempts to add `outEmpno` to 'Roll', which is a string.  And that's why your program hurls ORA-06502.

The solution is to use the correct concatenation operator, which is a double pipe:

```
dbms_output.put_line('Roll '||outEmpno)
```

There are other ways of concatenating strings, which listed in the documentation.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/operators003.htm#sthref817).

Comment: thankyou for ur quick response, sorry i did a mistake im not using that line, i forget to comment the line.